# Display Date as May 1st of 2011 Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date

I have a date column with several dates, I needed the query to display the date as

```
- January 1st of 1999 -
```

with the dashes.

Could anyone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put fixed values in the date format mask by [enclosing them in double quotes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#sthref406):

```
with t as (select date '1999-01-01' as dt from dual)
select to_char(dt, 'fm"-" Month ddth "of" YYYY "-"')
from t;

TO_CHAR(DT,'FM"-"MONTHDDTH"OF"YYYY"-"')
---------------------------------------
- January 1st of 1999 -
```

Or to show today's date:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'fm"-" Month ddth "of" YYYY "-"') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'FM"-"MONTHDDTH"OF"YYYY"-"')        
-----------------------------------------------------
- October 2nd of 2013 -
```

The [`fm` 'fill mode' modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#BABDAEDF) stops it padding the month name out with spaces, and removes the leading zero you'd normally get from `dd`.

The double-quotes are actually optional around the dashes since they're allowed anyway (`'fm- Month ddth "of" YYYY -'` works fine too), but in this case I'd probably quote them anyway to show they're unusual.